# Ícones em CSS intermitente ao recarregar página

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core

Estou tendo problemas no carregamento de ícones, mas é raro e difícil de reproduzir o problema, pois ocorre de vez em quando na atualização com F5.
Só ocorre em ícones css do bootstrap ou de oura fonte css qualquer como o Ionicons.

Os css estão em arquivo.

Segue alguns exemplos de como está exibindo os ícones quando o problema ocorre.

[image: Um exemplo do ícone com falha]

[image: Outro exemplo]

**Exemplo do css do arquivo "ionicons.css"**

```
.ion-edit:before { content: "\f2bf"; }
```

**Utilização da class no html**

```
<td>
        <a class="button_table" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDiv" onclick="load()">
            <span class="ion-edit"></span>
        </a>
    </td>
```

Inspecionando aqui a tela o css carregou desse jeito:

```
.ion-edit:before {  content: "ïŠ¿";}
```

Agradeço quem puder ajudar.

EDIT:
Os arquivos css estão configurados em bundleconfig.json do Asp .NET Core para realizar o minifier e são inseridos em apenas um cshtml de layout.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Resolvi aqui.
Alterei duas coisas.

A primeira era que um dos arquivos de css não estava explícito o tipo de charset a ser usado e aí o .net atribui um charset default do windows. Deixei explícito para usar UTF-8.

> @charset "UTF-8";

E Segundo é que os arquivos css dos ícones estavam todos configurados para um mesmo arquivo Minifier no bundleconfig.json junto com vários outros css, somente após isolar os arquivos na configuração para serem únicos no minifier o problema parou de ocorrer.